# WP7 One RunWorkerCompleted event firing for two BackgroundWorker objects

Tags: c#, multithreading, silverlight, windows-phone-7, backgroundworker

I have a few objects that inherit from a BaseOperation class. These include IntializeOperation, SignOnOperation, SignOffOperation, etc.

The BaseOperation class has an Execute() method that uses a BackgroundWorker to do tasks, including making service calls. I realize this is probably not the best design, but it's what I'm working with right now and redesigning isn't feasible right now. Here is a simplified version of the class.

```
public void AsyncExecute()
{
    _result = DoOperation();
}

public void Execute()
{
    _worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    _worker.WorkerReportsProgress = false;

    _worker.DoWork += (s, e) =>
    {
        AsyncExecute();
    };

    _worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, e) =>
    {
        //Tell our callback what we've done
        if (_result is Exception)
            Failed(_result as Exception);
        else
            Succeeded(_result);
    };

    _worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

If I call one operation it works fine. However, if I call two Operations in quick succession, I run into problems.

When the first operation finishes, it calls RunWorkerCompleted twice, once for each operation. I know because I can breakpoint inside the RunWorkerCompleted delegate, it gets hit twice, and I can also check which operation I'm to confirm that it is in different operations each time it is called. I can breakpoint in the 2nd operation's DoOperation() method to confirm that it continues running even after the RunWorkerCompleted event fires for that operation.

I'm having trouble figuring out why the RunWorkerCompleted event is raised for both operations when only the first operation has completed.

Comment: You use the wrong name for "Execute".  It should be "BeginExecute".

Comment: Why is that? The code works correctly. I don't think it matters what it's called. I use it like SignOffOperation.Execute().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. I'm using ManualResetEvent in the DoOperation() method. If two operations are going at the same time, it thinks everything has completed.